# Nginx virtual host - Create and modify using PHP

Tags: php, nginx, shell-exec

I would like to create and modify the Nginx conf file/virtual host using PHP dynamically. I also need to run some Nginx commands like reload/refresh, so I am currently using shell_exec function and run shell commands. But I am getting a permission error. The error might be fixed when I give ownership for www-data. Is this considered to be a big security issue? Is there any other solution for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is a potential security risk - if someone manages to upload a PHP file inside your `document_root` he will be able to modify your nginX config.

Comment: Hi @IVOGELOV, Thanks for your reply. Do you think is there any other secure way to accomplish this?

Comment: Perhaps a Node.js (or Golang, or your preferred way) sitting in a folder which is not directly writable by PHP and then using cURL functions in PHP to send HTTP requests to this Node server ...